# Commandline Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line-arguments, windows-shell, shellexecute

Hello again Stackoverflow community,

Today I am trying to execute an application with commandline parameters in C#, that not realy difficult like I tried

```
Process.Start(foldervar + "cocacola.exe", "pepsi.txt");
```

Cocacola.exe writes and Log in its current folder. In my commandline I write it manually like this

```
C:\myfolder>cocacola.exe pepsi.txt
```

Works wonderful but if I try it in C# a total fail.

I read that C# parses the command as C:\myfolder>cocacola pepsi.txt, without the ".EXE" ending. And I tested it manually without the ending, and this does not work.

Now, my question is what is the correct way to get C# executing it C:\myfolder>cocacola.exe pepsi.txt with the ".EXE"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to start one program from another one?

Comment: Yes right, and i have the problem that Process.Start(foldervar + "cocacola.exe", "pepsi.txt");
does not start it like that C:\myfolder>cocacola.exe pepsi.txt but C:\myfolder>cocacola pepsi.txt and that will the program not work.

Comment: @ Blabla R No thats not what I am trying todo. with , foldervar + "pepsi.txt") you would change that arguments. Read the line before :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ProcessStartInfo

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

example:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.WorkingDirectory=@"c:\someplace";
    proc.StartInfo.FileName="cocacola.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments="pepsi.txt";
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
```

here is docs on the StartInfo properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: And where does my program know where cocacola.exe is?

Comment: Actually that worked with CD's helpful comment setting WorkingDirectory!!! Thank you too guys!!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `StartInfo` properties.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\myfolder\cocacola.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\myfolder\pepsi.txt";
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessStartInfo` has the `WorkingDirectory` property you should set to C:\myfolder

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot CD!! You helped me get it working, I combine your's and hatchet's post!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the working directory first

```
string foldervar = @"C:\myfolder";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = foldervar;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cocacola.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"pepsi.txt";
process.Start();
```

Setting the WorkingDirectory is equivilent to `cd`ing into the proper directory before running programs.  It's what relative paths are relative to.